# Do calculations between non related tables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm in charge of tracking the number of software licenses my company use.

I have access to a table that shows the licenses assigned to a user and another table with the total licenses we currently own bought by a department  (Table structure at the end of post).
I have no problem using either data source on their own to create dashboards that shows total assigned licenses by Department, or by License Name (for table assigned licenses) or to get total licenses bought segmented by department or by Name (for table total licenses).

However I have problems when I try to do some calculation between tables. For example. I want to create a table visual object that reflect the Licences bought by department table with 2 extra columns for Licenses assigned for that specific name and department, and also to show the licenses that department has left:

| Department | Licence | Total | Total assigned | Left |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IT | License A | 100 | 80 | 20 |
| IT | License B | 150 | 140 | 10 |

I have no idea how to do that on Power BI. Whenever I try to add the total assigned (from a measure that calculate the total licences assigned. Either way, I cannot make the calculation.

Table structure example

**Assigned Licenses table**

| UserId | Deparment | License Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| person001 | IT | license A |
| person002 | Sales | license A |
| person002 | Sales | license B |
| person003 | IT | license C |
| person004 | Legal | license B |
| person004 | Legal | license C |

Where person002, from Sales, has licence B and licence C assigned to them.

**Licenses bought by department table**

| Department | License | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IT | license A | 200 |
| IT | license C | 500 |
| Legal | license B | 150 |
| Legal | license C | 200 |

Where Legal bought 150 licenses B and 200 licenses C

I tried using a table visual object to add the columns from Licenses bought by department table and adding the extra column from a mesure that calculates the total amount of licenses (count) from Assigned licenses however this extra column always shows the same value for all the rows, and does not apply the segmentation.

However if I create a table with columns from the Assigned Licenses table, the segmentation works fine.

So, how could I achieve my calculation. I can do it in excel but not on power BI

Answer (score 2):

Add a composite key in both tables, just concatenating the `Department` and `License` columns. After that, establish a relationship between the tables using this composite key.

When using the `'Licenses bought by department'[Department]` and `Licenses bought by department'[License]` columns in a table visual, you can easily do a row count to get the number of assigned licenses:

```
# Assigned Licenses =
COUNTROWS ( 'Assigned Licenses' )
```

Edit: For the sake of completeness, you can do this calculation without adding composite keys and establishing a relationship, too. You can do this by making a "faux" relationship using `TREATAS` to transfer your filter context from one table to the other.

```
# Assigned Licenses = 
VAR _departments = VALUES ( 'Licenses bought by department'[Department] )
VAR _licenses = VALUES ( 'Licenses bought by department'[License] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        COUNTROWS ( 'Assigned Licenses' ),
        TREATAS ( _departments , 'Assigned Licenses'[Department] ),
        TREATAS ( _licenses , 'Assigned Licenses'[License] )
    )
```

This measure together with `'Licenses bought by department'[Department]` and `Licenses bought by department'[License]` columns in a table visual should do the trick.

Disclaimer: I have not tested the formulas, not at work!

Comment: Thanks I would try your method eventually I did make it work.
First. Using the ALL() function I generated 2 new tables from the Assigned_Licences: one from the License column and the other from the Department column. 
Then I linked both tables with the respective Department and License columns on the Licenses bought by department table and Assigned Licenses table.
Finally I created a Table Visual Object and added the Department [Department] column and the License[License] column as data, followed by the measures I calculated initially from the original tables AND IT WORKED.